# Parsing JSON with LINQ-style queries in Scala

Tags: json, scala, json4s

Suppose I need to parse a JSON (see below).

```
{
  success: true
  statusCode: 0
  statusMessage: "Ok"
  payload { ... } // some actual data
}
```

First, I am parsing the "status" fields to get an instance of `case class Status` (see below)

```
case class Status(success: Boolean, code: Int, message: String)

val json = parse(text) // text is a JSON above

val statusList = for {
    JObject(obj) <- json
    JField("success", JBool(success)) <- obj
    JField("code", JInt(code)) <- obj
    JField("message", JString(message)) <- obj
  } yield Status(success, code, message)
```

Does it make sense ?

The type of `statusList` is `List[Status]`. It contains a single `Status` item. If the parsing fails the `statusList` is empty. I *don't* like it since I want `Option[Status]` rather than `List[Status]`

I can easily convert `List[Status]` to `Option[Status]` with `headOption` but I would like to get `Option[Status]` directly.

Can I parse the JSON with `json4s` to get  `Option[Status]` *without* getting `List[Status]` first  ?

Comment: What in particular doesn't work right with `headOption` that would work right if you could "get `Option[Status]` directly"? I don't understand from your question.

Comment: `headOption` does work. It just looks awkward to get `List` first and then convert to `Option`.

Comment: Awkward in terms of code formatting or performance?

Comment: I don't care about performance too much here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XPath-like functions, together with `toOption`:

```
val statusOpt = for {
    JBool(success) <- (json / "success").toOption
    JInt(code) <- (json / "code").toOption
    JString(message) <- (json / "message").toOption
  } yield Status(success, code, message)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use json4s built-in [extraction](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#extracting-values). In your case `extractOpt` instead of `extract`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a for-comprehension, is the following class which implicitely adds an `unpack` method to a `JValue`:

```
case class UnpackableJValue(jv: JValue) {

  import scala.util.Try

  def unpack[A](f: JValue => A): A = f(jv)

  def unpackList[A](f: JValue => A): List[A] = jv match {
    case JArray(values) => values map f
    case _ => List.empty
  }

  def unpackOpt[A](f: JValue => A): Option[A] = Try(f(jv)).toOption

}

object UnpackableJValue {
  implicit def jvalue2unpackable(jv: JValue) = UnpackableJValue(jv)
}
```

The `unpack` method receives a function which is responsible to create a domain value from a `JValue`.

```
import UnpackableJValue._

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

case class Status(success: Boolean, code: Int, message: String)

val json = parse(
  """
    |{
    |  "success": true,
    |  "statusCode": 0,
    |  "statusMessage": "Ok",
    |  "payload": { }
    |}
  """.stripMargin)

val res = json.unpack[Status] { v =>
  val success = (v \ "success").extract[Boolean]
  val code = (v \ "statusCode").extract[Int]
  val message = (v \ "statusMessage").extract[String]

  Status(success, code, message)
}

println(res)
// Status(true,0,Ok)
```